# How to initiate the removal of a server from SCCM dictated from an outside source using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sdk, sccm

I cannot determine from the System Center Configuration Manager SDK website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/develop/core/misc/system-center-configuration-manager-sdk how to initiate the removal of a computer from all asset collections it may be a part of.

My company now has the ability to build, deploy, and destroy virtual servers all within a few hours.  All newly built servers automatically have the SCCM client installed.  The current SCCM policy is to remove servers from asset groups that have been inactive for 22 days consecutive days.  This is still needed for our legacy environment.

I have been informed from my VM team that there is already code that is automatically run after a virtual server is destroyed.  I want to include code that can reach out to our SCCM server to initiate the removal of the server that was destroyed.  I have never worked with this kind of approach before and have been unsuccessful on where to even start.  I believe it was called API or Hooks. 
 I would prefer using PowerShell for coding as that is the language I know.

Comment: So to clarify do you want to remove all direct collection memberships of one object or just delete the device from the sccm db? Also as you tagged powershell are you looking for a solution based on the sccm cmdlets (only available on a computer where the console is installed iirc) or rather on wmi?

Comment: I want to delete the device.  In doing so I would assume it would remove itself from all collections it was associated with as well.  As for how to remove the device, it would need to be code based as this is going to be part of a combination of powershell code to run after a viral server has been destroyed.  If WMI or CIM is the best way to go then that it what I would prefer to use.

Answer (score 0):

The WMI code to delete a record from sccm would be

```
$comp = [wmi]"\\<siteserver>\root\sms\site_<sitename>:sms_r_system.resourceID='<resourceid>'"
$comp.psbase.Delete()
```

To get the ResourceID you can query sms_r_system by name

```
(Get-WmiObject -computername <siteserver> -query "select resourceID from sms_r_system where name like '<computername>'" -Namespace "root\sms\s
ite_<sitename>").ResourceID
```

Keep in mind that this may produce more than one entry (which is the reason why we do not delete by name but by ResourceID, so it might be necessary to delete all of the records.

If you have access to the sccm cmdlets (only on a server where the sccm console is installed) it would be:

```
Get-CMDevice -Name <DeviceName> | Remove-CMDevice
```